# What is the significance of the second return root statement in the bst insert?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

In the following code in the insert function to insert a an item in bst I feel that there is no use of the second return statement since a node will be always added after leaf node.

```
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return newNode(key);
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    return node;
}
```

But when I remove this return statement I get a totally different output for the following driver code

```
int main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 50);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 70);
    insert(root, 60);
    insert(root, 80);
    inorder(root);  // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST
}
```

For the insert function with the second return statement in Insert function I get

```
20 30 40 50 60 70 80
```

For the insert function without second return statement

```
40 50 80
```

What is the reason of this discrepancy ?

The above code is taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/

PS: I am a newbie and this is my first question on the platform.

Comment: A function either returns something or doesn't. It can't have it both ways. If one code path returns a node pointer, all codepaths must return a node pointer. It's just a fundamental rule of the language. Since you have to return, something, might as well return the new node.

Comment: Newbies better avoid that geeksforgeeks garbage collection my all means.

Comment: You can replace the second return `return node;` with `throw "oopsies";`

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is undefined, but I suggest you try to use debugger to see what happens when you skip the second `return`. Or try to draw the recursive calls on a piece of paper, but debugger should be easier. Note in particular what gets assigned to `node->left` or `node->right` when they are not the leaves.

Comment: @Frank: It's not just "might as well", the recursive calls are completely dependent on it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair point.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks for the test case. I just realised that in your test case the function will get stuck in a recursive call if we do not return the node.

Comment: @Eljay it gave a segementation fault

Comment: It should not cause a segmentation fault.  It should cause an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 3):

Reaching end of non-void function except for `main()` without executing `return` statement invokes *undefined behavior*. Therefore, any result is allowed without the second `return` statement.

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.6.3 The return statement says:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined
> behavior in a value-returning function.

N3337 3.6.1 Main function says:

> If control reaches the end
> of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Comment: Besides the theoretical problem, there is the practical problem that his code needs the return value.